# Apt-Get not finding Packages

Tags: mysql, linux, package, apt

I`m currently trying to install the mysql packages for a rails 3 app via apt-get, so I can get the corresponding gems working.

When I run :

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```

I get:

```
E: Couldn't find package libmysql-ruby
```

I when try to update apt, I get:

```
Reading Package Lists... Done
Building Dependency Tree... Done
```

If this helps, apt got install via Fink for max osx (10.7)
I would appriciate anykind of help with this issue.

Comment: Ask in the Ubuntu forums/stackexchange, quicker and better answewers

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-mysql2 libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: Under ubuntu 20.04 LTS it's the only solution that have been working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple guess :

```
apt-cache search mysql | grep lib
```

Or just directly

```
apt-cache search libmysql-ruby
```

That may give you a hint to know if the package name is a little bit different.

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension error for mysql2,

Simply try with following commands,

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-mysql
```

& then

`sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'm not really sure this is a programming question... But try this one out:
apt-cache search libmysql-ruby to check for the package name and see if there is something else like it, or if that's a different spelling.